# Ordenar arreglo por mes y año, de igual manera semana y año Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un arreglo de la siguiente manera:

```
var monthYear = ["1-2016", "7-2015", "7-2016", "3-2016", "8-2016", "2-2016", "6-2016", "8-2015", "5-2016", "4-2016", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015"];
```

En este arreglo me muestra el mes y el año, yo quiero ordenarlo por mes y año y que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
 var monthYear = ["7-2015", "8-2015", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015", "1-2016", "2-2016", "3-2016", "4-2016", "5-2016", "6-2016", "7-2016", "8-2016"];
```

de igual manera en las semanas:

```
var weekYear = ["2015-30", "2015-31", "2015-32", "2015-33", "2015-34", "2015-35", "2015-36", "2015-37", "2015-38", "2015-39", "2015-40", "2015-41", "2015-42", "2015-44", "2015-49", "2016-06", "2016-09", "2015-43", "2015-45", "2015-46", "2015-47", "2015-48", "2015-50", "2015-51", "2015-52", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", "2016-13", "2016-14", "2016-15", "2016-16", "2016-17", "2016-18", "2016-19", "2016-20", "2016-21", "2016-22", "2016-23", "2016-24", "2016-25", "2016-26", "2016-27", "2016-28", "2016-29", "2016-30", "2016-31", "2016-32"];

var weekYear = ["2015-30", "2015-31", "2015-32", "2015-33", "2015-34", "2015-35", "2015-36", "2015-37", "2015-38", "2015-39", "2015-40", "2015-41", "2015-42", "2015-43", "2015-44", "2015-45", "2015-46", "2015-47", "2015-48", "2015-49", "2015-50", "2015-51", "2015-52", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-06", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-09", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", "2016-13", "2016-14", "2016-15", "2016-16", "2016-17", "2016-18", "2016-19", "2016-20", "2016-21", "2016-22", "2016-23", "2016-24", "2016-25", "2016-26", "2016-27", "2016-28", "2016-29", "2016-30", "2016-31", "2016-32"];
```

Intenté usar esta función pero no funciona:

```
monthYear = monthYear.sort(sortNumber);

function sortNumber(elem1, elem2){
        var as = elem1.split('-');
        var bs = elem2.split('-');
        if(parseInt(as[0])< parseInt(bs[0])){
          if(parseInt(as[1]) < parseInt(bs[1])){
            return -1;
          }else if(parseInt(as[1]) > parseInt(bs[1])){
            return 1;
          }else{
            return 0;
          }
        }else if(parseInt(as[0]) > parseInt(bs[0])){
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
```

De igual manera con las semanas, quisiera saber si la función esta mal o si existe una manera más fácil de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está muy bien lo que estás haciendo, sólo hay que corregir el orden en que lo comparás:

```js
var monthYear = ["1-2016", "7-2015", "7-2016", "3-2016", "8-2016", "2-2016", "6-2016", "8-2015", "5-2016", "4-2016", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015"];

function sortNumber(elem1, elem2) {
    var as = elem1.split('-');
    var bs = elem2.split('-');
    if (parseInt(as[1],10) < parseInt(bs[1],10)) {  //Primero comparar el año
        return -1;
    } else if (parseInt(as[1],10) > parseInt(bs[1],10)) {  //o si es mayor
        return 1;
    } else if (parseInt(as[0],10) < parseInt(bs[0],10)) { //año igual => mes
        return -1;
    } else if (parseInt(as[0],10) > parseInt(bs[0],10)) { //o si el mes es mayor
        return 1;
    } else { //y si ambos son iguales
        return 0;
    }
}

console.log(monthYear.sort(sortNumber));
```

Nótese que [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) siempre debe llevar el segundo parámetro. En este caso `10` (base 10).
<sup>*Gracias a [@devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept) por recordarlo.</sup>

El otro caso te lo dejo como ejercicio.

Comment: Debes especificar siempre el *radix* cuando usas `parseInt()` de esta forma `parseInt(numero, 10)`. Lee https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funcionó :)

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo un pequeño "`truco`" para ordenar las fechas:

Teniendo en cuenta tu Array `weekYear` :

```
var weekYear = ["2015-30", "2015-31",...];
```

Viene en la forma perfecta para comparar los "`números`", es decir,

```
201530 < 201531 < ... < 201601 < ....
```

Así pues compara en la función `sort` los números generados de quitar `-` y generar el número.

Para el Array `monthYear`, debes hacer un paso previo, `agregarle un "0" si el número del mes es menor que 10` y comparar el número generado **anteponiendo el año a la semana** :

```js
var weekYear = ["2015-30", "2015-31", "2015-32", "2015-33", "2015-34", "2015-35", "2015-36", "2015-37", "2015-38", "2015-39", "2015-40", "2015-41", "2015-42", "2015-44", "2015-49", "2016-06", "2016-09", "2015-43", "2015-45", "2015-46", "2015-47", "2015-48", "2015-50", "2015-51", "2015-52", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", "2016-13", "2016-14", "2016-15", "2016-16", "2016-17", "2016-18", "2016-19", "2016-20", "2016-21", "2016-22", "2016-23", "2016-24", "2016-25", "2016-26", "2016-27", "2016-28", "2016-29", "2016-30", "2016-31", "2016-32"];

var sortWeekYear = weekYear.sort(function(a, b){
  return +a.split('-').join('') - +b.split('-').join('');
});

console.log(sortWeekYear);

var monthYear = ["1-2016", "7-2015", "7-2016", "3-2016", "8-2016", "2-2016", "6-2016", "8-2015", "5-2016", "4-2016", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015"];

var sortMonthYear = monthYear
.map(function(el){
  var parts = el.split('-');
  if(parts[0].length <=  1) parts[0] = '0' + parts[0];
  return parts.join('-');
})
.sort(function(a, b){
  return +a.split('-').reverse().join('') - +b.split('-').reverse().join('');
});

console.log(sortMonthYear);
```

Comment: Pues ya que lo dices el array me llega sin el `"-"` es decir `201631` lo que hago es poner el `-` y asi poder ordenarlo